# I finished my Virtual environment setup in Python. I didn't have django in pip list, but i can still create django project using django-admin command

Tags: python-3.x, django

pip list:
Package    Version

---

pip        23.1.2
setuptools 58.1.0

it doesn't have django in My Virtual environment but still django-admin commands worked for me! how is that possible.

Thank you for clear answers in advance

i Tried finding django package in lib folder but still doesn't contain any packages related to django

Answer (score 3):

it is looks likely that Django is installed globally on your system.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a virtual environment, the purpose is to create an isolated system that is separate from the rest of your "virtual environment." This relationship should be seen from all directions, other systems won’t communicate with the “virtual” environment. Unless programmed otherwise, but this is not the case.

If you run ‘django-admin’ and the terminal understands what you want it means that this SPECIFIC terminal knows what you want. In your case, the django-admin is already installed on your system since you executed `pip install django` outside your virtual environment.

Always pay attention to which shell is being used.

```
PS C:\Users>
```

“PS” = PowerShell

```
(Playground) PS C:\Users\
```

($PROJECT_NAME) PS = [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) with PowerShell